# Proving the formula for the distance of vectors from hyperplanes

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

For $p, q \geq 1$, $p$ and $q$ conjugate, that is $\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{q} = 1$, $\frac{|\alpha \cdot h(x)|}{\|\alpha\|_p}$ is the norm-$q$ distance of $h(x)$ to the hyperplane of equation $\alpha \cdot h(x) = 0$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391)